# FancyBox play sound on beforeShow-event

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, fancybox

I want to play a sound on fancybox-open (beforeShow).

**My solution at this point:**

```
beforeShow: function(){
        $("body").css({'overflow-y':'hidden'});
        var audio = new Audio('other/sounds/error.mp3');
        audio.play();
    }
```

But i have remarked that the sound dont get played on mobile devices.

Maybe someone knows an other way to play the sound on html5 standart?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which browser are you using on your mobile device?

Comment: chrome, i want a solution that plays the sound on every browser?

Comment: Can you make a list which are working and which are not?  
Maybe stupid question, but are you sure the sound is turned on?

Comment: yes the sound is turning on, i dont have the capacity to test all browsers. My solution above normaly works on every browser? On PC all works fine.

Comment: Use [mediaelement js](http://mediaelementjs.com/) for cross-device/cross browser compatibility (of course any flash media won't play on Apple mobile devices) ... then check [this post](http://www.picssel.com/play-mp4-videos-with-mediaelement-js-in-fancybox/), which is for videos but you could adapt it for sound too

Comment: JFK, thank you, how can i play then the sound on my example above? Thx